# Safely test rom build

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, custom-roms, rom, 6.0-marshmallow

I'm attempting to get into Android Rom development and as such I've compiled CM13 from source for my device (which is not yet fully supported, I've tweaked it so that it ought to work). However, due to the fact that this is my first foray into custom Rom development I have one rather serious issue.

How do I safely test my rom?

I want to be able to flash it to my device (Oneplus Two) using TWRP however, I need to be able to ensure that no permanent damage can be done to my device. How could I do this?

Any help will be appreciated hugely!

Comment: You can try Android Emulator I guess.

Comment: @SarpSTA, that's the point. You can't just use an emulator, because you need to test it on real hardware. AFAIK you need to take a risk here. As a ROM developer you are (morally) responsible for the users who flash this ROM onto their devices. Have you checked out xda-developers already? Maybe one of the devs is willing to test your ROM.

Comment: @GiantTree Oh. He meant hardware-like? Well, other than trying it on a hardware, one can not know for real.

Comment: @SarpSTA I know about many ROM projects especially for Samsung's Exynos devices and the devs are clearly not asking: "Does the Android part work?" Because it certainly does, it's unchanged. But rather: "Do all the drivers and tweaks work, so I can use it?" Many devices, brick either soft or hard and James is asking for a way to protect himself from a hardbrick when testing. The only real answer I have is: "You need to take the risk. Unless you can emulate all the hardware exactly like on your phone, you are out of any other options."

Comment: Apart from that, my friends, this clearly is a development-related question – and thus off-topic here. This site focuses on end-users.

Comment: Guess it's time ti take the risk then, cheers anyway! @Izzy sorry, never realized this was end-user only.

Comment: @JamesHughes many don't (we've get our part of dev questions everyday). Spread the word :) And good luck!